# Boot logo aspect ratio failure during boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I have seen this over time with more than one laptop/motherboard:

For example, the round "HP" logo is displayed, then - before asking for LUKS password, it is horizontally compressed. (becoming oval)

I suspect those things bite me when moving to another(bigger) SSD's - and using Boot-Repair.

I did try;
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)

any other suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Other than the visual irritation, are there any problems, such as the computer does not boot?

Comment: What you describe is before the OS has loaded so boot repair I doubt will do anything. Nor will anything you do with the DE.

Comment: Yes, the issue is purely cosmetic. I've seen this on 22.04, and 22.10 .. and just caused it on a 23.04  - I remember that it was on a 22.10 after cloning a disk, when installing 23.04beta  , It was suddenly fixed, then - after moving the disk to another laptop,(abd using Boot-repair)  - it got messed up again.